# Ho to pass a Model Object or a Viewbag to Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc4 with C#. I get the details from `Getdeatils()` method of student class. This method return an array. `Getdetails` method also have same fields like `studentBO`. In the controller I have a method like follows

```
   public ActionResult Index()
            {
          List<studentBO> list = new List<studentBO>();
                    Student.GetDetails[] dt = Student.Getdeatils();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Length; i++)
                {

                            studentBO.name= dt[i].name;
                            studentBO.studentno= dt[i].studentno;
                            studentBO.address= dt[i].address;
                            list1.Add(studentBO);
                  }    
          ViewBag.Registrationlist = list1;
           return View(list1);
        }
```

`studentBO` object have 3 fields

```
public class studentBO
    {      
        public long studentno{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string address{ get; set; }
}

How can I get viewbag or model in my Jquery  `$(document).ready(function () {}` function. I want to get every students name. So I have to use foreach loop as well.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serialise your item in the ViewBag and write it to the view, so that the Javascript code will be able to read it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var registrationList = @(Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewBag.Registrationlist)));
    for (var i = 0; i < registrationList.length; i++) {
        var studentno = registrationList[i].studentno;
        var name= registrationList[i].name;
        var address= registrationList[i].address;
        // write some more code to make use of the values
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano Dalpiaz. var registrationList is an object then how to get the values for specific fileds? I want to get studentno and name.

Comment: That variable should be rendered as a Javascript array, so there might be more than one student in it. I have modified my answer to show how to get those values.

Comment: Hello, i tried ur solution but its not working.in registrationList the value is storing like system.generic..........

Comment: this answer deserves more attentions, at least it work for simple List with customized class

Answer (score 1):

Use WebAPI to create a service that returns your objects. Then you can use an ajax-call in your Javascript code to fetch the objects.

WebAPI:

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController
{
    IEnumerable<Student.GetDetails> GetDetails()
    {
        List<studentBO> list = new List<studentBO>();

        Student.GetDetails[] dt = Student.Getdeatils();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Length; i++)
        {

            studentBO.name= dt[i].name;
            studentBO.studentno= dt[i].studentno;
            studentBO.address= dt[i].address;

            list1.Add(studentBO);
        }   

        return list1; 
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.getJSON("api/students")
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of students.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          //Do something with the student object
        });
      });
});
```